# Use SharePoint 2007 workflow to append text to multiline text field

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow

I'd like set up a SharePoint workflow to add text to a multi-line text field when a specific value is set in another field.

For example:

1. Status field is set to "In Progress."
2. The workflow adds "5/28/14 In Progress" to Status History field.
3. Status field is set to "Complete."
4. The workflow adds "5/30/14 Complete" to Status History.
5. Status History now contains "5/28/14 In Progress 5/30/14 Complete"

I can construct multi-level conditions to handle the various statuses, but I'm stuck on which action to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think,

1. You would have to create an hidden field in the list to store the last value of the "status" field. So every time the list entry is modified, the workflow starts, you compare the "status" field and the hidden field, if difference found, trigger the "logging" action, otherwise stop the workflow.
2. For the "logging" action, you will have to define some workflow variable first, to get the current date, and "Build Dynamic String" to construct a string that is made of "Status History" + "current date" + "New status" and by "Set Field in Current Item" to save the result back to the "Status History"